# Initialize a kotlin MutableStateFlow without an initial value

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-flow

I am learning kotlin flow and slowly converting code in my company app from livedata to kotlin flow. So I have question:

In my Viewmodel I had livedata variable "status" like this:

var status: MutableLiveData = MutableLiveData()

and I observed it in MainActivity.

Now I want to do same thing with flow. I converted all emiting/colleting parts and other things and everything works fine, but have one problem. This is declaring part of my variable status:

`var status: MutableStateFlow<Status> = MutableStateFlow()`    -> this code gives error. I need to pass value for parameter in the brackets

So I have to write it like this:

```
var status: MutableStateFlow<Status> = MutableStateFlow(Status.Failure("adding value even though I don't want to"))
```

Can anyone explain me is there any way to initialize this same as before in livedata without providing initial value? Thanks

Comment: Maybe you need to switch to `MutableSharedFlow`?

Comment: By design Stateflow must always have a value that will be emitted to its subscribers which makes it good candidate for UI state holders. Consider `SharedFlows` instead. If your subscribers do not require values when they subscribe until the first emit. Chaneels are good for single subscriber stream like for navigation events etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't, Mutable stateFlow require an initial value.

One way is to set this value nullable and init it with null.

But it's a trick and there is another way using channel and receive it as flow :

```kotlin
private val _status = Channel<Status>() 
val status = statusChannel.receiveAsFlow()
```

Comment: Kotlin Channel will not work with multiple observers

Comment: Then you can't update the state as easy as StateFlow and you have to emit it and use coroutines scope for it